# UIPickerView delegate inside of TableViewCell not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a TableViewCell that contains a UIPickerView. The problem is, that the delegate of UIPickerView is not getting called

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testCell") as! TableViewCell
        
        cell.setupCell(indexPath: indexPath.row)
        
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    public var picker = UIPickerView()
    private var index = 1
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        print("awakeFromNib")

        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self        
    }
    
    public func setupCell(indexPath: Int) {
        print("setupcell")
        index = indexPath

        contentView.addSubview(picker)
        
        picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        picker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        picker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        picker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
    }
}

extension TableViewCell: UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {        
        return 3
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return "abc"
    }
}
```

I tried to reload picker using         `picker.reloadAllComponents()`, but then only `func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView)` is getting called. What am i missing? The problem is for sure with my cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return cell that you setup instead of new cell  `UITableViewCell()`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testCell") as! TableViewCell
        
        cell.setupCell(indexPath: indexPath.row)
        
        return cell //UITableViewCell()
    }
```